# sed: moving elements in a line around

Tags: sed, perl

So I want to do something like this in Perl:

```
if (/number=[0-9]*;/){ print "$&$`$'";}
```

Is this possible in sed? That is, I want to isolate a part of a line and move it from the middle to the front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\(number=[0-9]*;\)/\2\1/'
```

However, if there were several occurrences of `number[0-9]*;`, that would move the last one (because of the *greedy* `.*`). To move the first one:

```
sed -ne 's/number=[0-9]*;/\
&\
/; s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)\n/\2\1/p'
```

That is, not use `.*`, but wrap the (first this time) occurrence of the pattern inside newline characters (the only character that cannot otherwise occur in the pattern space), which makes the match uniquely identifiable my the next `s` command.

That assumes the input is valid text (in particular that there are no sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters).

You can also use `perl` on the command line like with:

```
 perl -pe 'if (/number=[0-9]*;/) {$_ = "$&$`$'"}'
```

Or

```
 perl -pe 's/(.*?)(number=[0-9])/$2$1/'
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -ne 's/number=[0-9]*;/\n&\n/; s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\1\3/p'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think though that I might not have been clear enough: this will trim everything prior to the "number=" part, right? I want to preserve everything before number=, but to move the captured part to the front.

Comment: @JohnVerghese No, it won't trim, but exchange as you wanted. The line is cut into three parts, which are referred to by the escaped digits `\1` and so on. `\2\1\3` means you exchange the first part (before the pattern) with the second part (the pattern).